# Timer and updating label text

Tags: vb.net, timer

im trying to make an app to show when there is somthing "new". So i made Label1 and Timer. I want every secound to check if in status.txt text is 0 to show nothing, if its 1 to show text from text.txt. This is what try so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim status As String = client.DownloadString("http://force-play.com/launcher/status.txt")
    Dim information As String = client.DownloadString("http://force-play.com/launcher/text.txt")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If status = 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "No New Info"
        End If
        If status = 1 Then
            Label1.Text = information
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And?  Don't see a question...

Comment: Every time the timer ticks you need to update the status.  Status looks like it will only get set once here..

Comment: also - probably not your issue, but you are setting your interval after starting the timer .. not right ..

Comment: @APrough: How to update/refresh form every secound to check if the status.txt is changed to 1 to show text.txt

Comment: As @Kenny points out, you will have to update status and information within your timer event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `status` string at the beginning of your `Timer1_Tick` method.